# TypeScript error with Promise.reject

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, arguments

Why do I receive the following compilation error with this TypeScript method which I wrote:

```
getFile(path: string): Promise<FileEntry> {
  return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(path)
    .then(entry => {
      if (entry.isFile) {
        return <FileEntry>entry;
      } else {
        let err = new FileError(13);         
        err.message = 'input is not a file';
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    });
}
```

I get the error:

```
Argument of type '(entry: Entry) => Promise<never> | FileEntry' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Entry) => PromiseLike<never>'. Type 'Promise<never> | FileEntry' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<never>'. Type 'FileEntry' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<never>'. Property 'then' is  missing in type 'FileEntry'.
```

The definition for `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` is as follows:

```
resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(fileUrl: string): Promise<Entry>;
```

`FileEntry` is a subclass of `Entry`, hence the casted return. However, the error is around `Promise.reject`.

If I change my reject line to the following, it works:

```
return Promise.reject<FileEntry>(err);
```

Do I need to return `Promise.reject(...)` and what is the correct implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return a promise you create a new Instance of a promise and return this instance. The constructor takes a function that receives the resolve and reject callbacks you should call, when your logic succeeds or fails.

To let your promise "return" your result, you don't write `return result`, but call `resolve(result)`.

```
getFile(path: string): Promise<FileEntry> {
  return new Promise<FileEntry>((resolve, reject) => {
    // Your logic here.
    // call resolve() on success
    // or reject() on failure
  });
}
```

So in your case it should look like the following:

```
getFile(path: string): Promise<FileEntry> {
  return new Promise<FileEntry>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(path)
    .then(entry => {
      if (entry.isFile) {
        resolve(<FileEntry>entry); // Success
      } else {
        let err = new FileError(13);         
        err.message = 'input is not a file';
        reject(err); // Error
      }
    });
  });
}
```

If you want to learn more about promises read for example here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really return a resolved or rejected promise inside of your promise chain.

When you want to indicate an error you should just throw an error:

```
else
   let err = new FileError(13);         
   err.message = 'input is not a file';
   throw err;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the `return entry` with a Promise.resolve.
This solved when I had a similar error.

```
getFile(path: string): Promise<FileEntry> {
  return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(path)
    .then(entry => {
      if (entry.isFile) {
        // See this
        return Promise.resolve(<FileEntry>entry);
      } else {
        let err = new FileError(13);         
        err.message = 'input is not a file';
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    });
}
```

You won't have to write the verbose `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})` because your underlying `this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` already returns a Promise and you can chain on it. (Which I feel is the correct way.)